# Why do AWS RDS Databases have a publicly available feature in addition to ordinary security groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Amazon RDS Databases have two layers of access security: a binary "yes/no" publicly accessible setting which shows/hides the database endpoint outside the VPC as well as ordinary security groups.

Without making it publicly available you cannot connect to the database from outside the VPC.

Why do RDS databases have this publicly available feature at all? Why not just use ordinary security groups like other resources? Is it a relic of old architecture or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same thing as the "Assign Public IP" flag on EC2 instances, and it does the same thing. Since public IPs are a scarce resource, Amazon wants to make sure you actually need that, and requires you to enable it specifically.